# Firebase offline functions on iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I use Firebase offline functions, in particular I use it to determine when the user was last online or he is online. During testing, I encountered such a problem that if I do logout, the Disconnect function does not work, although I do not cancel Disconnect functions. I understand that before logout, I can send this data myself, but then the meaning of this function will disappear from the box. Tell me how can I fix this?

This function determines the activity of the user and I call it in `MainTabBarController` (it is used as root controller)

```
func setupLastSeenActivity() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            let realmManager = RealmManager()
            guard let currentUserID = realmManager.getCurrentUser()?.id else { return }
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                let ref = Database.database().reference().child(MainGateways.users.rawValue).child(currentUserID)
                let userSearchLocationRef = Database.database().reference().child(UserSearchLocationKeys.userSearchLocationModel.rawValue).child(currentUserID)

                let parameters = [UserSubgateways.isOnline.rawValue : true]
                ref.updateChildValues(parameters, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in

                })

                userSearchLocationRef.updateChildValues(parameters, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in

                })

                let disconnectParameters = [UserSubgateways.isOnline.rawValue : false, UserSubgateways.lastSeenTimeStamp.rawValue : ServerValue.timestamp()] as [String : Any]

                ref.onDisconnectUpdateChildValues(disconnectParameters, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                    guard let _error = error else { return }
                    debugPrint(_error.localizedDescription)
                })

                userSearchLocationRef.onDisconnectUpdateChildValues(disconnectParameters, withCompletionBlock: { (error, ref) in
                    guard let _error = error else { return }
                    debugPrint(_error.localizedDescription)
                })
            }
        }
    }
```

A logout function from `FirebaseAuthManager`

```
  func logOut(completion: (() -> Void)?) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            do {
                let pushNotificationManager = PushNotificationManager()
                pushNotificationManager.unregisterPushNotification()
                pushNotificationManager.removeTokenWhenLogOut(success: nil)
                // Observers
                FIRFriendsDatabaseManager.shared.observeNewFriend(false, success: nil, fail: nil)
                FIRFriendsDatabaseManager.shared.observeFriendRemoved(false, success: nil, fail: nil)
                let firChatCardManager = FIRChatCardManager()
                firChatCardManager.syncChatCardModels(false)

                FacebookManager.logOut()
                Database.database().reference().removeAllObservers()

                let firebaseGeneralDatabaseManager = FirebaseDatabaseGeneralManager()
                firebaseGeneralDatabaseManager.logOut()
                try Auth.auth().signOut()
                let realmManager = RealmManager()
                realmManager.logOut()
                let appManager = AppManager()
                appManager.logOut(isDeleteAccount: false, completion: completion)
            } catch {
                debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A user can be connected without being signed in. A user can be signed in without being connected. Both are normal and expected behavior. What is the specific use-case you are trying to implement with the onDisconnect handler?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I'm trying to realize the possibility of correctly reflecting the status of the user, namely Online / offline. But I also thought that onDisconnect handler is not ideal for this, since a user can log into his account from several devices, and for example only one device will lose the Internet connection. Tell me, Firebase takes into account the number of connections per user, if so, where to find information on how to use it.

Comment: The [presence sample in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-sample) tracks multiple connections per user, precisely for this reason.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen ok, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a cloud function that counts the number of connected devices, if the number of connected devices is 0, then I set the value isOnline = false and set the lastSeenTimeStamp

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

module.exports = functions.database.ref('userOnlineDevices/{userID}/{onlineSystemModelID}')
    .onWrite(event => {

        const snapshot = event.data;
        const userID = event.params.userID;
        const onlineSystemModelID = event.params.onlineSystemModelID;

        const currentData = event.data.current;
        const previousData = event.data.previous;

        console.log("currentData.val()", currentData.val(), "previousData.val()", previousData.val());

        if (currentData.val() && !previousData.val()) {
            // value created

            const checkUserRef = admin.database().ref("users").child(userID);
            const checkUserRefPromise = checkUserRef.once("value", function(checkUserRefSnap, error) {
                if (error) {
                    return console.log("created checkUserRefPromise error", error);
                }
                if (checkUserRefSnap.val()) {
                    const checkUserID = checkUserRefSnap.val()["id"];
                    if (checkUserID == null) {
                        return console.log("checkUserID == null")
                    } else {
                        console.log("checkUserID", checkUserID)
                    }

                    const recentActivityTimeStamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
                    const userRef = admin.database().ref("users").child(userID);
                    const userRefPromise = userRef.update({
                        "isOnline": true
                    });

                    const userSearchLocationModelRef = admin.database().ref("userSearchLocationModel").child(userID);
                    const userSearchLocationModelRefPromise = userSearchLocationModelRef.update({
                        "isOnline": true,
                        "recentActivityTimeStamp": recentActivityTimeStamp
                    });

                    return Promise.all([userRefPromise, userSearchLocationModelRefPromise]);
                } else {
                    return console.log("checkUserRefSnap.val() == null")
                }
            });

            return Promise.all([checkUserRefPromise]);
        } else if (!currentData.val() && previousData.val()) {
            // value removed
            const checkUserRef = admin.database().ref("users").child(userID);
            const checkUserRefPromise = checkUserRef.once("value", function(checkUserRefSnap, error) {
                if (error) {
                    return console.log(error);
                }

                if (checkUserRefSnap.val()) {
                    const checkUserID = checkUserRefSnap.val()["id"];
                    if (checkUserID == null) {
                        return console.log("checkUserID == null")
                    } else {
                        console.log("checkUserID", checkUserID)
                    }

                    if (userID) {
                        const removedTimeStamp = new Date() / 1000;
                        const userRef = admin.database().ref("users").child(userID);
                        const userRefPromise = userRef.update({
                            "isOnline": false,
                            "lastSeenTimeStamp": removedTimeStamp
                        });

                        const userSearchLocationModelRef = admin.database().ref("userSearchLocationModel").child(userID);
                        const userSearchLocationModelRefPromise = userSearchLocationModelRef.update({
                            "isOnline": false,
                            "lastSeenTimeStamp": removedTimeStamp
                        });

                        return Promise.all([userRefPromise, userSearchLocationModelRefPromise]);
                    } else {
                        return console.log("removed, userID == null");
                    }
                } else {
                    return console.log("removed, checkUserRefSnap.val() == null");
                }
            });

           return Promise.all([checkUserRefPromise]);
        } else {
            // updated
            const checkUserRef = admin.database().ref("users").child(userID);
            const checkUserRefPromise = checkUserRef.once("value", function(checkUserRefSnap, error) {
                if (error) {
                    return console.log(error);
                }

                if (checkUserRefSnap.val()) {
                    const checkUserID = checkUserRefSnap.val()["id"];
                    if (checkUserID == null) {
                        return console.log("checkUserID == null")
                    } else {
                        console.log("checkUserID", checkUserID)
                    }

                    const recentActivityTimeStamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
                    const userRef = admin.database().ref("users").child(userID);
                    const userRefPromise = userRef.update({
                        "isOnline": true
                    });

                    const userSearchLocationModelRef = admin.database().ref("userSearchLocationModel").child(userID);
                    const userSearchLocationModelRefPromise = userSearchLocationModelRef.update({
                        "isOnline": true,
                        "recentActivityTimeStamp": recentActivityTimeStamp
                    });

                    return Promise.all([userRefPromise, userSearchLocationModelRefPromise]);
                } else {
                    return console.log("updated checkUserRefSnap.val() == null");
                }
            });

            return Promise.all([checkUserRefPromise]);
        }
    });
```